# How to Pass Parameters to an Custom interaction Request

Tags: prism

I would like to pass a parameter while calling Raise method of Interaction Request which could be data bound to the view in the interaction request.

How to achieve this behavior?

Thanks in advance.

Noufal

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass parameters through the Raise call.  You could try using a custom view (https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Wpf/blob/master/InteractivityQuickstart/InteractivityQuickstart/Views/CustomPopupView.xaml) and add properties that you can use to data bind your data to, or use a custom dialog service instead.